# ListBox not showing all items on Portrait or Landscape modes

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm just getting started on WP7. I wanted to know if there's a more proper way to do this, but for now this seems to be the most logical one. I'm trying to display a list of countries with their associated phone codes, like so:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ScrollViewer Name="ScrollViewer" Height="3500">
        <StackPanel Name="StackPanel" Height="3500">
            <ListBox Name="codeList"  FontSize="26" SelectionChanged="codeList_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBoxItem Name="US">United States (+1)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="AG">Afghanistan (+93)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="AR">Argentina (+54)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="AU">Australia (+62)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="AS">Austria (+43)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="BE">Belgium (+32)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="BU">Bulgaria (+359)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="BR">Brazil (+55)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="CL">Chile (+56)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="CN">China (+86)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="CO">Colombia (+57)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="DK">Denmark (+45)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="EG">Egypt (+20)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="FR">France (+33  )</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="DE">Germany (+49)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="GR">Greece (+30)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="HN">Hungary (+36)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="IN">India (+91)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="IT">Italy (+39)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="JP">Japan (+81)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="MX">Mexico (+52)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="ND">Netherlands (+31)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="NO">Norway (+47)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="PE">Peru (+51)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="PO">Poland (+48)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="PT">Portugal (+351)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="ES">Spain (+34)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="SE">Sweden (+46)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="SW">Switzerland (+41)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="TK">Turkey (+90)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="UR">Uruguay (+598)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="VE">Venezuela (+58)</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="ZI">Zimbabwe (+263)</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

It turns out that on Portrait mode, the list is only shown up to Poland, and on Landscape until Greece. It doesn't matter how much I increase the Scrollviewer and StackPanel sizes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StackPanel and the ScrollViewer are unnecessary in this layout, as the ListBox scrolls all on its own. The problem is you are not constraining the height of the Grid row, which is causing the item in the Grid Row to take up as much height as necessary. Just add the following:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

...underneath the Grid tag, then delete the ScrollViewer and StackPanel tags, and you should be good to go.

Let me know if it doesn't work and I'll try it myself. That's just off the top of my head.

HTH!

Comment: Worked like a charm. Couldn't test it until tonight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with AdvancedREI.

If you are using default project template, then you have set grid, to be in the top row of the parent which size is set to auto:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

And its giving listbox size of the whole page, limiting it. So, if you want to set list box on a whole page, use this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                <ListBox Name="codeList"  FontSize="26">
                    <ListBoxItem Name="US">United States (+1)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="AG">Afghanistan (+93)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="AR">Argentina (+54)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="AU">Australia (+62)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="AS">Austria (+43)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="BE">Belgium (+32)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="BU">Bulgaria (+359)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="BR">Brazil (+55)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="CL">Chile (+56)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="CN">China (+86)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="CO">Colombia (+57)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="DK">Denmark (+45)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="EG">Egypt (+20)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="FR">France (+33  )</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="DE">Germany (+49)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="GR">Greece (+30)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="HN">Hungary (+36)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="IN">India (+91)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="IT">Italy (+39)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="JP">Japan (+81)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="MX">Mexico (+52)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="ND">Netherlands (+31)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="NO">Norway (+47)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="PE">Peru (+51)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="PO">Poland (+48)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="PT">Portugal (+351)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="ES">Spain (+34)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="SE">Sweden (+46)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="SW">Switzerland (+41)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="TK">Turkey (+90)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="UR">Uruguay (+598)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="VE">Venezuela (+58)</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="ZI">Zimbabwe (+263)</ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**And i see you have forgotten Latvia in the country codes, we also like great new apps =)**

Comment: I'll add Latvia, but this is not meant to be a full-fledged App (yet) :P